# Проблемы при создании сервиса

Tags: bash, perl, unix, centos

Всем привет! 
Centos 7

Проблема в следующем:
Если в консоли пишу:

```
/opt/dklab_realplexor/dklab_realplexor.int start
```

Всё ОК, сервис запускается.
Если создаю файл сервиса и делаю так:

```
systemctl start realplexor
```

то сервис падает в ошибку (при этом не пишет ни куда почему) и не создается PID файл.
Подскажите, из-за чего это может быть?
Внутри dklab_realplexor.int запуск perl скрипта с параметрами.

```
cd $CWD && $BIN $CONF -p $PIDFILE 2>&1 | logger -p `eval "echo $LOGPRI"` -t `eval "echo $LOGTAG"` &
```

Полный файл сервиса:

```
[Unit]
Description=realplexor

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/dklab_realplexor_dklab_realplexor.conf.pid
WorkingDirectory=/opt/dklab_realplexor

User=root
Group=root

Environment=RACK_ENV=production

OOMScoreAdjust=-1000

ExecStart=/opt/dklab_realplexor/dklab_realplexor.int start
ExecStop=/opt/dklab_realplexor/dklab_realplexor.int stop
ExecReload=/opt/dklab_realplexor/dklab_realplexor.int reload
TimeoutSec=5000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что установлено 2 перла

Comment: Если нужно 2 перла, то используйте [`perlbrew`](https://perlbrew.pl/)

Comment: Проблема в этом вопросе решилась после исправления этой http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591005/centos-7-не-видит-perl-под-рутом/