# Centos 7 не видит perl под рутом

Tags: perl, centos, sudo, root

Всем привет!
У меня следующая проблема в Centos 7:
захожу под рутом и выполняю команду:

```
ls `perl -e "print qq(@INC\n);"`
```

получаю:

```
perl5
```

Далее делаю:

```
sudo su
```

и следом

```
ls `perl -e "print qq(@INC\n);"`
```

и получаю пути перла и подключенные модули.

Если я без sudo su пытаюсь запустить любой скрипт примерно так:

```
perl blabla.pl
```

ничего не происходит и не на что не ругается.

Вопрос в том - почему? Что не так с рутом? Почему под ним не работает perl?

Выполняю:

```
$ echo $PATH; type perl; which perl; file $(which perl)
```

Из под рута:

```
[root@game ~]# echo $PATH; type perl; which perl; file $(which perl)
/root/perl5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
perl is hashed (/usr/local/bin/perl)
/usr/local/bin/perl
/usr/local/bin/perl: empty
```

из под sudo su:

```
[root@game ~]# echo $PATH; type perl; which perl; file $(which perl)
/root/perl5/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
perl is hashed (/bin/perl)
/bin/perl
/bin/perl: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=68e24ea1ba03faac3442ad4d448635bc8feceb4b, stripped
```

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу, вывод команы `$ echo $PATH; type perl; which perl; file $(which perl)` в обоих случаях.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, из под sudo su: `[root@game ~]# echo $PATH; type perl; which perl; file $(which perl)
/root/perl5/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
perl is hashed (/bin/perl)
/bin/perl
/bin/perl: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=68e24ea1ba03faac3442ad4d448635bc8feceb4b, stripped`

Comment: из под рута: `[root@game ~]# echo $PATH; type perl; which perl; file $(which perl)
/root/perl5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
perl is hashed (/usr/local/bin/perl)
/usr/local/bin/perl
/usr/local/bin/perl: empty`

Comment: чтобы дополнить вопрос, нажмите, пожалуйста, [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, готово

Comment: переопределение перемонной `PATH` (вероятно, в каком-то из файлов `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/root/.bashrc`, `/root/.bash_profile`, `/root/.bash_login`, `/root/.profile`) с выбрасыванием каталогов `/bin` и `/sbin` из её содержимого, а также создание пустого исполнимого файла `/usr/local/bin/perl` сделано намеренно?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, нет, не специально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[root@game ~]# echo $PATH; type perl; which perl; file $(which perl)
/root/perl5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
perl is hashed (/usr/local/bin/perl)
/usr/local/bin/perl
/usr/local/bin/perl: empty
```

очевидно, что пустой файл `/usr/local/bin/perl` надо удалить (или хотя бы переименовать).

а также следует добавить в содержимое переменной окружения `$PATH` каталоги `/sbin` и `/bin`. лучше, вероятно, это сделать, убрав переопределение этой переменной, происходящее в каком-то из файлов: `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/root/.bashrc`, `/root/.bash_profile`, `/root/.bash_login`, `/root/.profile`.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/perl - это FreeBSD-way, в линухах, ЕМНИП, это /usr/bin/perl

Comment: @Majestio, http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html

Comment: я пожалуй процитирую оттуда "This is the source code for the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS), a
standard for laying out filesystems for UNIX-like systems.  It is the
recognized standard for most Linux systems." ... Ключевое слово "most". На самом деле же всем давно "закон не писан". FreeBSD 9.0 /usr/bin/perl, FreeBSD 11.0 /usr/local/bin/perl, Linux Funtoo /usr/bin/perl, Mac OS X 10.9.1 /usr/bin/perl ... это из того что под рукой.

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что что-то не так с путями ($PATH)

- пробуем найти, используем под рутом: find / -type f -iname "perl"
- на найденных (желательно очевидных) используем: /полный_путь/perl -v
- работающий перл с полным путем найден, осталось править окружение, а именно $PATH, где править в комментах перечислили

И еще ... "/root/perl5/bin" - должно озаботить!!! SYSROOT-овый перл, это что-то не из нашей галактики. Вычищайте, выверяйте пути каждой учетной записи.

Comment: *пробуем найти* — зачем искать то, что уже «найдено»? см. самую последнюю строку в тексте вопроса.

Comment: если в путях есть "/root/perl5/bin" должно настораживать ... а не несколько ли копий/версий перла в системе. "Ваши" whereis или which просматривают только что каталогах, доступных по путям. Команда find ищет все, от нее ничего не уйтет. Вот как-то так. Посему ваше "найдено" еще перепроверить нужно бы.

Comment: *перепроверить* — зачем проверять то, что уже проверено? цитата из вопроса: «и получаю пути перла и подключенные модули». // мне кажется, вы не совсем поняли изложенное в вопросе. впрочем, неудивительно — вопрос изложен очень сумбурно.

Comment: блин! поэтому я и предложил сперва find'ом пройтись! есть вероятность наличия нескольких копий перла/симлинков/убитых симлинков. Только запуск с абсолютным путем и опцией взятия версии покажет, что исполняемый файл живой и исполняемый. Хотя ... посыпаю голову пеплом, да, в find нужно добавить опцию -type f, чтобы исключить симлинки.