# python -V centos7 пытается запустить /usr/local/bin/python вместо /usr/bin/python в bash

Tags: python, centos

```
# python -V
-bash: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

Почему питон может ссылаться на эту директорию?

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 8209704 Mar  3 15:03 /usr/bin/python.
```

Символических ссылок вроде нет.
Сам питон находится в директории /etc/bin/python.

```
# which python
/usr/bin/python
```

И он нормально работает:

```
# /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  3 2017, 15:03:33)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> f=10
 >>> print (f)
 10
 >>>
```

Comment: [то же](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591005/591020#comment793502_591005), но для python.

Comment: наберите `type python` или `command -v python` в bash  и обновите ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте проверить здесь:

```
alternatives --list
```

Эта штука может давать подобный эффект.